# QtWidget-based Android style preview in designer?

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt5

When creating a QtWidget (non-QtQuick) based Android app, it is shown with *Android* styling per default on device (since Qt 5.4), but with *Qt default* style in Qt Designer and compiled for *Desktop* target.

Is there a simple solution to have the Android target *look'n'feel* in Qt Designer as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android style `QAndroidStyle` is only built when building Qt for Android, therefore it is not available on other OS like Windows, Linux or macOS.

The reason is likely to be technical as this style will likely query Android for info like the font, color theme, etc. Those queries will not work or maybe even not compile on a non Android OS.

Other styles have such restriction like `QWindowsXPStyle` and `QWindowsVistaStyle` on Windows and `QMacStyle` on macOS.

So, no there is no simple solution for what you are asking.
The easier way is to build an app and run it on an Android device or on a Android virtual device.

It **might** also be possible to update `QAndroidStyle` to make it work on other OS by adding some code to make it use default values instead of querying Android when built on another platform. But this is not simple and maybe even not possible at all.